# Is $f(x)=0$ Even or Odd function or both?

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

At present I know that, a constant function is an EVEN function.

But my teacher said that if a constant function has value $0$ then it is both EVEN and ODD.

I just want to verify this and want know the reason for this.

Comment: It's both; check the definitions

Comment: check for yourself. if $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, then what can you say about $f(-x)$? $-f(x)$? why does this fail for the constant function $g(x)=1$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Yes thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's even because $0 = f(x) = f(-x) = 0$, and it's odd because $0 = -0 = -f(x) = f(-x) = 0$. So it's both!